# getting the first word of the string and deleting the word from actual string

Tags: c++

Starting with:

```
string str = "10110111 12345 54321 2345321 1236543";
```

Grabbing the first word `10110111` and deleting it from the actual string.
After getting the word in a `string word;` the new string should be:

```
string str = "12345 54321 2345321 1236543";
```

I am using stringstream for getting the word.

```
stringstream ss(str);
string word;
ss>> word;
```

Now how should I delete this word from the string?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase

Comment: i am having different length of words, erase works on characters. how to specify the word?

Comment: A word is just some number of characters isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first idea is to find position of the first space and substring your string.

```
std::string s("1234 asdf zxcv 0987");
std::cout << s << std::endl; // "1234 asdf zxcv 0987"

size_t space_pos = s.find(" ");    
if (space_pos != std::string::npos) {
  s = s.substr(space_pos + 1);
}

std::cout << s << std::endl; // "asdf zxcv 0987"
```

Comment: `auto` is introduced in C++11 standard. I edited code for your to be compatible with previous standard.

Comment: @shahjahankhokher: the `auto` is from C++11.  If you're not using C++11 mode, do so; if your compiler doesn't support C++11, get one that does.

Comment: i am new to c++, how to use c++11?

Comment: As a heads up I don't think this will pull out the first word in a string with only one word (ex: "hello"). Just might be something to look out for (not specified by op if the string would always have more than 1 word)

Comment: in my case this string is having 100's of words each work would be atleast 5 characters long. will this code work fine?

Comment: @shahjahankhokher it will work, except it won't remove last word of your string. If you want to do that write `else` to `if` statement where you clear `s` variable.